# How to use firebase auth correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently trying to use google firebase in my web application.

```
import '../login.css'
import {auth} from '../firebase'
import {signInWithEmailAndPassword} from 'firebase/auth'
export default function Login() {

    const[email,Setemail]=useState(''); 
    const[password,Setpassword]=useState('');
 
    const trackMail=(e)=>{
Setemail(e.target.value)
    }
    const trackpas=(e)=>{
        Setpassword(e.target.value)
    }
        
    const handleSignin = async function (){=
         let usercred= await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password)
                console.log(usercred.user); 
        }
        const handleSignUp=()=>{
        
        }
        const handleForgot=()=>{
            
        }
  return (
    <div> 
        <form className="form">
  <div className="form-inner">
    <h2>LOGIN</h2>
    <div className="input-wrapper">
      <label >Username</label>
      <div className="input-group" ><span className="icon">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M12,4A4,4 0 0,1 16,8A4,4 0 0,1 12,12A4,4 0 0,1 8,8A4,4 0 0,1 12,4M12,14C16.42,14 20,15.79 20,18V20H4V18C4,15.79 7.58,14 12,14Z"></path>
          </svg></span>
        <input type="text" value={email} onChange={trackMail}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="input-wrapper">
      <label >Password</label>
      <div className="input-group"><span className="icon">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M11.83,1.73C8.43,1.79 6.23,3.32 6.23,3.32C5.95,3.5 5.88,3.91 6.07,4.19C6.27,4.5 6.66,4.55 6.96,4.34C6.96,4.34 11.27,1.15 17.46,4.38C17.75,4.55 18.14,4.45 18.31,4.15C18.5,3.85 18.37,3.47 18.03,3.28C16.36,2.4 14.78,1.96 13.36,1.8C12.83,1.74 12.32,1.72 11.83,1.73M12.22,4.34C6.26,4.26 3.41,9.05 3.41,9.05C3.22,9.34 3.3,9.72 3.58,9.91C3.87,10.1 4.26,10 4.5,9.68C4.5,9.68 6.92,5.5 12.2,5.59C17.5,5.66 19.82,9.65 19.82,9.65C20,9.94 20.38,10.04 20.68,9.87C21,9.69 21.07,9.31 20.9,9C20.9,9 18.15,4.42 12.22,4.34M11.5,6.82C9.82,6.94 8.21,7.55 7,8.56C4.62,10.53 3.1,14.14 4.77,19C4.88,19.33 5.24,19.5 5.57,19.39C5.89,19.28 6.07,18.92 5.95,18.6V18.6C4.41,14.13 5.78,11.2 7.8,9.5C9.77,7.89 13.25,7.5 15.84,9.1C17.11,9.9 18.1,11.28 18.6,12.64C19.11,14 19.08,15.32 18.67,15.94C18.25,16.59 17.4,16.83 16.65,16.64C15.9,16.45 15.29,15.91 15.26,14.77C15.23,13.06 13.89,12 12.5,11.84C11.16,11.68 9.61,12.4 9.21,14C8.45,16.92 10.36,21.07 14.78,22.45C15.11,22.55 15.46,22.37 15.57,22.04C15.67,21.71 15.5,21.35 15.15,21.25C11.32,20.06 9.87,16.43 10.42,14.29C10.66,13.33 11.5,13 12.38,13.08C13.25,13.18 14,13.7 14,14.79C14.05,16.43 15.12,17.54 16.34,17.85C17.56,18.16 18.97,17.77 19.72,16.62C20.5,15.45 20.37,13.8 19.78,12.21C19.18,10.61 18.07,9.03 16.5,8.04C14.96,7.08 13.19,6.7 11.5,6.82M11.86,9.25V9.26C10.08,9.32 8.3,10.24 7.28,12.18C5.96,14.67 6.56,17.21 7.44,19.04C8.33,20.88 9.54,22.1 9.54,22.1C9.78,22.35 10.17,22.35 10.42,22.11C10.67,21.87 10.67,21.5 10.43,21.23C10.43,21.23 9.36,20.13 8.57,18.5C7.78,16.87 7.3,14.81 8.38,12.77C9.5,10.67 11.5,10.16 13.26,10.67C15.04,11.19 16.53,12.74 16.5,15.03C16.46,15.38 16.71,15.68 17.06,15.7C17.4,15.73 17.7,15.47 17.73,15.06C17.79,12.2 15.87,10.13 13.61,9.47C13.04,9.31 12.45,9.23 11.86,9.25M12.08,14.25C11.73,14.26 11.46,14.55 11.47,14.89C11.47,14.89 11.5,16.37 12.31,17.8C13.15,19.23 14.93,20.59 18.03,20.3C18.37,20.28 18.64,20 18.62,19.64C18.6,19.29 18.3,19.03 17.91,19.06C15.19,19.31 14.04,18.28 13.39,17.17C12.74,16.07 12.72,14.88 12.72,14.88C12.72,14.53 12.44,14.25 12.08,14.25Z"></path>
          </svg></span>
        <input type="password"  value={password} onChange={trackpas}  />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="btn-group">
      <button className="btn btn--primary" onClick={handleSignin}>Sign in</button>
      <button className="btn btn--tertiary" onClick={handleSignUp}>Sign Up</button><br/> 
    </div>
    <div className="btn-group"> 
      <a className="btn--text" href="#0" onClick={handleForgot}>Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

this is the code for the login page
The handlesignin function is trying to get the User object from firebase auth,
but as soon as I click on the sign-in button, nothing is consoled.
What is the possible reason for so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prevent your form from submitting and also handle login errors:

```js
const handleSignin = async function (event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Email: ", email); 
  console.log("Password: ", password); 
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
    console.log("Email After User Creation: ", user.email);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Comment: can you also let me know what was the possible reason my function wasn't running

Comment: I think you your form was submitted when you clicked on the signin button so the page reloaded and there were no time for your function to be executed.